# How to program arduino with ic2 for a liquid crystal lcd screen?

Tags: lcd

I am trying to get text characters to come up on my liquid crystal lcd screen. it's a 16x2 screen. It only uses four pins...gnd, 5v, scl, and sda pins. I'm not sure what how to program it since all I'm finding online is how to program it if my screen has 16 pins to connect for programming. I believe the address for my lcd screen is 0x27.

Thanks, Eduardo

it's the Arduino Uno. I'm trying to get my LCD to display "Voltage= (variable)". I can write text now. I have a pot wired to my arduino. I'm want to get a voltage number to come after equals sign. How can I program it so when I turn the pot that the actual voltage will come after "Voltage="?

Here's my program

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> 
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2); 
void setup() 
{ 
lcd.init(); 
lcd.backlight(); 
int sensorPin = A0; 
int sensorValue = 0; 
sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin); 
lcd.print(("Voltage=") + analogRead(sensorPin)); 
} 
void loop() { }
```

Comment: i2c devices are supposed to be fairly standard.  Have you got your circuit right for i2c? http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/acatalog/I2C_Tutorial.html

Comment: it's the Arduino Uno.  I'm trying to get my LCD to display "Voltage= (variable)". I can write text now. I have a pot wired to my arduino. I'm want to get a voltage number to come after equals sign. How can I program it so when I turn the pot that the actual voltage will come after "Voltage="?

Comment: Here's my program
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);                                void setup()
{
lcd.init(); // initialize the lcd 
lcd.backlight();
int sensorPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;
sensorValue = digitalRead(sensorPin);
lcd.print(("Voltage=") + digitalRead(sensorPin));
}
void loop()
{
}

Comment: please edit your question if it has changed, please include any additional information in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry about that, Paul.  I'm new to the forum and didn't know I had the ability to edit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a pot connected to my Arduino Uno.  This code shows the characters "Voltage=(sensorValue).  This way I can turn my pot and my LCD will show how many volts the potentiometer is pushing out.

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  
void setup()
{
}
void loop()
{
lcd.init();                      
lcd.backlight();
int sensorPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;
sensorValue = 0.004882812 * analogRead(sensorPin) + 1;
lcd.print("Voltage=");
lcd.print(sensorValue);
}
```